# PHP Strips tags from column and then update database

Tags: php, html, mysql

So right now I have php that strips html from a column in a table in a database. Looks like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id_199 FROM exp_data");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo strip_tags($row['id_199']);
      echo "\n";
    }
```

When I echo that, I get everything from the column (id_199) without html so I know its working. Keep in mind not every row in that column has content in it. My question is how can I extend this code to now update the database with the text with no html?

Let me clarify further, I want to achieve two things.

1. Strip html from data in a column
2. Update that column to now replace the old data with the stripped data

How does once achieve this?

Comment: it is better to use `strip_tags()` before inserting value into database

Comment: So if all the values are there already then do I remove them, strip them then insert them?

Comment: If you want to update a column you will also need a unique column like an auto_increment id to update that specific row

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `id_199` FROM `exp_data`");
$data = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(!empty($row['id_199'])) { //Check for empty value
        $data[$i] = array($row['id'] => $row['id_199']);
        $i++; // $i + 1
    }
}
```

First you need to store the striped data in a new array.
After that you can do a `foreach()`on that array:

```
foreach($data as $i) { // Foreach $i
    foreach($i as $id => $row) {
        $query = "UPDATE `exp_data` SET `id_199` = '$row' WHERE `id` = '$id'";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    }
}
```

As you can see you will also need an other id or another column that is unique to update the `id_199` column. This might not be the entire answer for your problem but it should at least get you started.